# Batch code exporting variable to text file automatically adds " symbol at beginning and end

Tags: batch-file

For some reason, whenever i try to export the testing variable to a text file it automatically adds " at the beginning and the end but i dont want them to be there because then the next "program" wont work with them. (if you want to know what the variable is: testing= `start "" C:\something\something.exe & exit` ) 
but it is exported in the text file as: `"start "" C:\something\something.exe & exit"`
I first tried this code:

```
>hi.txt echo %testing%
```

but that didnt worked because there are spaces in it then i tried this code:

```
>hi.txt echo "%testing%"
```

That worked but it adds " at the end and beginning of the text inside the txt file 
so then i tried

```
echo "%testing%" >hi.txt
```

but then happens exactly the same thing.

I think this is just something wrong in my code but i can't find it.

Anyone know why this happens?

Thanks for ur time and sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: If you read the help instead of searching the internet. `echo %testing% > hi.txt` and just to be sure leave spaces around the redirection character -it sometimes matters.

Comment: I already tried that but then the batch file crashes and stores nothing inside hi.txt

Comment: In a batch you have to escape special characters. You have ampersand in %testings%. You are starting programs weirdly. There is noting to parse the special characters.

Comment: So it isnt possible? or do i have to do it with delayed expansions or something?

Comment: No you have to write simple code. Even though it's one line it convoluted. `echo C:\something\something.exe > file.txt` should be sufficient. See my answer here on how to start programs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371443/what-do-all-commands-in-batch-mean-and-do

Comment: What editor is this? Quite unusual. Why not use a good editor instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only way of generating the batch file is via an editor that adds quotation marks at the beginning and at the end, then type

```
start" "" c:\something\something.exe & exit "
```

This will result in

```
"start" "" c:\something\something.exe & exit ""
```

so that

- the `start` command alone is in quotes,
- the rest is ok
- and the trailing `""` does not matter

Note that this will only work for executables, not for built-in commands like `if`, `for` and `echo`. Build-in commands will not be recognized and more.

Comment: Ty that works, but then another piece of code isnt working anymore:        `IF "%testing%"=="" (
set "test=nothinginside"
)`

Comment: `if` is a build-in command, the same for `echo`. That won't work

Comment: Do you know another way to check if the testing variable is empty then store variableisempty to another variable  ?

Comment: You could probably program a small executable that does the job regarding the condition check. However, manipulating environment variables will not be easy, since that program will get its own copy of it.

Comment: @RealmoINL If the variable is empty it is not defined, so `if not defined testing ... `